# Update Ionic in the existing project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, bower, updates

I was excited to see the Release version of Ionic, but found myself unable to update my existing project. Here is what I did.

1. run `npm install -g ionic`
2. Open `bower.json` in your App's root folder (the one above **www**)
3. You will find something like this here:

   ```
    {
      "name": "MyAppName",
      "private": "true",
      "devDependencies": {
        "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#xxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
   ```
4. Change it to this (basically by changing the last line:

   ```
    {
      "name": "MyAppName",
      "private": "true",
      "devDependencies": {
        "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.0.0-rc.1"
      }
    }
   ```
5. Save the file
6. Go to command line and run this in your App Folder

   ```
    bower update
    ionic lib update
   ```
7. Run `ionic lib` to check the version number

### Edit

This post relates to Windows OS, as I am using 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: The @Borja solution worked for me under MacOS X 10.11 El Capitan

Answer (score 15):

I also had a lot of problems to update an existing ionic project. This is what I did to solve the issue:

- Remove `bower.json` from `www/lib/ionic`
- Execute `ionic lib update` from the source project.

This action will ask for confirmation, just type `yes` and your project will be updated to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution that worked for me... Tried many other options too.

Comment: Really help full but i got an error : invalid version

Answer (score 4):

You need not touch the `bower.json` file.

After `npm install -g ionic`, be in the root folder of your app and run this command:

`ionic lib update`

This will prompt you if you want to upgrade your project's Ionic version, i.e download and copy the new Ionic libraries.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for the existing projects. I already tried that.

Comment: It should. I have done that on my Ubuntu 12.04, which had `1.0.0-beta.14` and I updated it to `1.0.0-rc.1`.

Comment: Oh, I see. There are possibilities of bugs; could you try uninstalling and then re-install npm and ionic?

Comment: I am already done with the above listed process. I posted this just to help others facing the same issue. Have added Windows thing also in the Edit.

Comment: If that is what you meant, you should check this post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/
And good that you mentioned it's for Windows, but you should mention which version of Windows was it.

Comment: Yep! that's correct. I have added the Windows version in the post, i.e. Windows 7, 64 bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73337/discussion-between-keval-and-anjum).

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded my `ionic` project from `ionic v1.0.1` to `v1.1.0` to  by upgrading the command line tool with `npm` and then generating a start project to see what changed. Here's exactly what I did:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic

npm install -g ionic
```

Then `ionic start tabsAppX tabs` to create a starter project. When I compared it to a starter project created from the *previous version* of `ionic`, I saw that only the `www/lib/ionic` folder changed (to the newest version). So I simply copied that into my actual project and ran `gulp scss` to update my css files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did while using version 1:

1. Created a new project
2. Deleted all the content of www folder
3. Copied all the content of my earlier project
4. Pasted there in the new project

*Make a point while doing ionic start old-project-name --type ionic1 keep the old-project-name to not to cause any problem later on*